# Rounding Down 1 value

Tags: php

I'm struggling a little and looking for help. I have a table called products and the two important columns are productPrice and productRewards.

I can manually insert the data, through the form, in my admin console and all my products display, just fine.

Essentially, I would like to take the value of my productPrice field and use floor() to round this down and apply to the productRewards field.

Example: if admin entered 199.99 into productPrice's input field 199 would automatically be input into the productRewards field.

```
if(isset($_POST['add_product'])) { 

$productRewards = $_POST['productRewards'];
$productPrice = $_POST['productPrice'];

$query = "INSERT INTO products( productPrice, productRewards ) VALUES ";
$query .= "( {$productPrice}, {$productRewards} ) ";

$add_product_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
}
```

The above is the 2 columns that are relevant to inserting the data from the admin form into my database.

I am struggling to figure this out, I know how to use the floor() function, but I can't get the value of one inserted value and convert it, before the data is sent. I tried changing my value to:

```
"INSERT INTO products ( productRewards ) VALUES "; ( {floor $productPrice} ) ";
```

But if I enter 23.99 the data inserted into my database is 24. So I'm sending the data, but phpMyAdmin is rounding up, as it is an integer column, so my data is at least going to the right place, but my logic is wrong, as my floor() function is not doing what I want it to do (I know I'm not asking it properly :/ ). Any pointers would be greatly received, thanks.

Comment: Did you try floor( $productPrice )  ?

Comment: I did, but as I was in an SQL string I didn't get my parentheses in the right place and I got the wrong result.  But I have it, now, after scaisEdge showed me the correct way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do directly in sql

```
  "INSERT INTO products ( productRewards ) VALUES ( FLOOR($productPrice) ) ;"
```

but should not use php var in sql you are at risk for sqlinjection

so you should take a look at you SQL driver for binding_param

Comment: Thank you, I was kind of close and I appreciate your pointing me to the correct way of doing it, thanks. I am going to change my SQL later, to reduce SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using PDO for this instead of SQL functions like that.  That may not directly solve your problem but it's a much better practice so you aren't as vulnerable to SQL injection.

You can do that with this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['add_product'])) { 

$productRewards = floor($_POST['productRewards']);
$productPrice = floor($_POST['productPrice']);

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db = 'dbname';
$user = 'dbusername';
$pass = 'dbpass';
$charset = 'dbcharset';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO products(productPrice, productRewards) VALUES (:productPrice, :productRewards)');
$query->bindValue(':productPrice', $productPrice, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':productRewards', $productRewards, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$add_product_query = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

You could also just use floats in the database too :)

Comment: Thank you, I do intend to use PDO, at a later date. It's a uni project and thus far everything has been MySQLi, in lessons. But I have used PDO before and will be changing it to that later, as I understand the vulnerabilities of what I presently have, which is why I haven't escaped anything. But thank you for your advice, it's definitely encouraged me to follow it up soon.

Comment: I would use it anyways because after finding out how to use PDO I found it easier to use PDO queries than non PDO ones.